# Incrementing a value and printing every step with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a list of values. Basically I'm trying to calculate columns widths for photoshop template, with JS. It looks like this : one 15px gutter, one 52px column, one 15px gutter, one 15px gutter, one 53px column, one 15 px gutter. Basically I need to add 36 values to my initial value, and print every step of that calculation.

So my loop consists of 6 elements. Here is what I did :

```
col1 = 52;
col2 = 53;
gutter = 15;
result = 145;

for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    result = result + gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();
    result = result + col1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();
    result = result + gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();
    result = result + gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();
    result = result + col2;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();
    result = result + gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();
}
```

If I replace innerHTML with a console.log, it will work perfectly. But I think it's better if it works with innerhtml. The problem is, with that function, the div#result will only show the last value of result variable. And I want to see every step..

By the way I think my function could be written better. There's a lot of repetition in it

EDIT : here is the updated code thanks to gillesc, as you can see its quite ugly but it works

```
col1 = 52;
col2 = 53;
gutter = 15;
result = 145;
space = "<br/>";

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    result += gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString() + space;
    result += col1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString() + space;
    result += gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString() + space;
    result += gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString() + space;
    result += col2;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString() + space;
    result += gutter;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString() + space;
}
```

Comment: `+=` to append, `=` to replace. So stop replacing the `innerHTML` and `append` to it. `+=` works for number too so `result = result + gutter;` can simply be `result += gutter`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell what your expected output is. Can you explain what you want your final html to look like?

Comment: well gillesc was right I had to use append and not replace.. I'm gonna edit with the new code

Comment: why do you do `space.toString()` it's already a string. `innerHTML += result.toString() + space`. And really you should build a string you append to and edit innerHTML once only, less browser rendering.

Comment: yes I definitely need to write this in a more elegant way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more elegant way. Build up an array and use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create your spaced string. Updating `innerHTML` only once.

`+=` to append, `=` to replace. So stop replacing the `innerHTML` and append to it. `+=` works for number too so `result = result + gutter;` can simply be `result += gutter`.

Added `var` everywhere as well to avoid those variables being on the global scope.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oonzm02g/)

```
var col1 = 52;
var col2 = 53;
var gutter = 15;
var result = 145;
var space = " ";
var html = [];


for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    html.push(result += gutter);
    html.push(result += col1);
    html.push(result += gutter);
    html.push(result += gutter);
    html.push(result += col2);
    html.push(result += gutter);
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html.join(space);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the `innerHTML` element every time. Stop doing `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toString();` and `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result.toString();`.

Small notes:

1. The loop runs 7 times not 6.
2. Run `document.getElementById('result');` once before the loop to improve performance.
3. You don't need to `result.toString()`, JS is smart enough to convert it when appending  to a string.
4. I would suggest doing:

   ```
   const col1 = 52, col2 = 53, gutter = 15, result = 145;
   const elem = document.getElementById('result');

   for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
       elem.innerHTML += (result += gutter);
       elem.innerHTML += (result += col1);
       elem.innerHTML += (result += gutter);
       elem.innerHTML += (result += gutter);
       elem.innerHTML += (result += col2);
       elem.innerHTML += (result += gutter);
   }
   ```

Comment: how will the loop run 7 times when `for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {`? It would if `i <= 6` but not when `i < 6`.

Comment: on my first iteration I did put i <=6 by mistake

Comment: @gillesc: I wrote this before the OP edited his question.